# Printing the number of files having the same name for every file from a directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, files, directory

I am new to Linux and I have an assignment which requires writing a shell script that prints all the names of both files and subdirectories of a directory (given as parameter) and this should also print the number of files with the same name for every file from this directory.

My problem is that I was able to print the names of all files and directories and also to do the second part of the task, but I can't bring them together, which means that my output has two different parts:

```
/some/path
a1  
a2 
a3

a1 1
a2 1
#a1, a2 files and a3 directory
```

And it should look like this:

```
a1 1
a2 1
a3
```

This is the code that I used writing my shell script:

```
#the first part that prints all the names from the directory
mydir=$1
cd $mydir
ls -l $mydir | awk '{print $9}'

#the second part that prints the number of files with the same name for every file
file=$(find $mydir -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort | uniq -c)
echo $file
```

Comment: Does the existing answer solve your problem? If so, don't forget to mark one with the checkmark; thank you! If not, let us know what happened.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of a "learning Linux/shell scripting" assignment, I would suggest something along these lines:

```sh
mydir=$1

for f in "$mydir"/*
do
  printf "%s %d\n" "$f" $(find "$mydir" -name "$f" -print 2>/dev/null | wc -l)
done
```

Adjustments from your script:

1. no need to `cd` to the directory in order to `ls` it
2. no need to `awk` the filename; you could just `ls` it, but ...
3. running the `ls ... awk` separately from the `find` means you got separated output
4. no need to specially print the `find` output if all you're doing is counting it
5. no need to sort the output if all you're doing is counting it
6. no need to use `uniq` if you're trying to catch all
7. I took the liberty of removing `-type f` in case your assignment would want you to find *directories* of the same name
8. added `-name "$f"` to have `find` match only files with matching names
9. use `printf` to combine the filename and counts into the same line of output
10. no need to parse the output of `ls` in order to get the filename(s); that's what `for f in "$mydir"/*` -- in particular, the `*` -- does; it expands to match filenames.

I've also quoted all of your variable usages, in case the user provides a filename such as `"this file"`.

This won't show hidden files in the output; you could add `shopt -s dotglob` to have the `"$mydir"/*` expand to match dotfiles (hidden files) as well.

As an advanced caveat, this will mis-count filenames that have newlines in them,  provided that the user passes in a newline-containing filename to look for.

Comment: I must apologize for the delayed response to your comment; your suggestions were a really great help for me and I managed to get my assignment done in time because of this. Thank you!